# How to tag an untagged question using a rare technology?

Tags: discussion, tags

### Introduction (you can skip this if you're lazy)

Okay, so the story begins when I read this article by Jeff Atwood:

*[The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)*

In which I discover what a meta tag is and also that a special tag called `untagged` exist for question without tags.

Being curious I search for them on Stack Overflow and I only find two, the first one being a closed one on the verge of deletion, while the second one seems a decent average question.

In my candid enthusiasm I told myself "hey, let's give it the appropriate tag it deserves", so I check on the question, and it looks like it's talking about a JavaScript library called `vexi` since there is JSON-like script next to a `<textarea>` HTML tag. So I go ahead and replace the untagged tag with `javascript` only to notice afterwards (by searching the web and finding the main page of that very library which happens to be a framework: http://vexi.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) that it is not JavaScript, but a language specific to that very framework.

So the appropriate tag should be `vexi`, but there are only eight questions on the whole Stack Overflow website that mention this technology and most of the time it's just as an example or a suggestion (i.e the main question is not about `vexi`). Therefore there is probably not enough need for this tag to exist.

The said question can be found here:

[How to add a custom context menu to a textarea in Vexi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346890/how-to-add-a-custom-context-menu-to-a-textarea-in-vexi)

### Question (tl;dr)

What tag should a question using a rare technology have instead of `untagged`?

Comment: The fact that the language for a given question is rare doesn't mean using the tag is wrong.  It means that people are unlikely to find the question, but that's what happens with questions about obscure topics.

Comment: @pnuts So is this the right thing to do ? If so, can someone put it explicitly as an answer ? :)

Comment: @Servy post an answer ? :)

Comment: What I wonder why no one previously added the [tag:user-interface] and [tag:contextmenu] tags. They seem to fit very well with the question.

Comment: Also Vexi is not a Javascript library. It is a custom language/platform written in Java (so not browser based) which is written in XML and JS-like.

Comment: http://vexi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I was the 1st to close the other ***untagged - tagged*** [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32111209/4099593). To be frank I am searching for the [delete] link on that question and I am still unable to find that. I also wanted to edit out *Thanks* in the question but the \[edit\] link was disabled. The post was locked after it was closed. I am unable to see how :-(

Comment: @pnuts I think Charles was addressing the line in the question of _"...and it looks like it's talking about a JavaScript library called `vexi`..."_

Comment: @pnuts Well, considering that's the only spot I see on this post that mentions it looking like a JavaScript library, it's entirely possible Charles accidentally overlooked the next sentence or just hurried to correct the claim in a comment. It's a common occurrence on the web.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Rushed the responses.

Comment: So what I would add is that, yes, Vexi is rarely mentioned at the moment. But any aspiring technology (and we still develop Vexi actively) looks to build profile, and surely being used on Stackoverflow is part of that.

I should mention: I am a Vexi developer. Also this question was asked by somebody else who uses Vexi but for some reason didn't want to post on Stackoverflow so I posted it and sent them here for the answer.

Answer (score -3):

It appears to me that you should not create a new tag specifically for this question - if you think the tag is unlikely to be used by other questions in the near future.

From the [Creating new tags help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from
>   the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6
>   month period.

I don't know whether 'some sites' includes Stack Overflow but we should probably assume that it does.

Comment: So what are you supposed to do ? Nothing ? :)

Comment: @Drax  Do nothing is my interpretation of the help. How would you interpret it?

Comment: I don't know and that's the very reason for this question ^^

Comment: @Drax It's a pity no one authoritative has commented. I think the help very clearly indicates you should not create a tag unless you fully expect it to be used on many questions. However, it's less clear to me that this policy actually makes any sense. I'd say create the tag if you want to, but be fully prepared for it to be deleted and don't lose any sleep over it.

Comment: I totally agree with your comment. Waiting for someone for a full answer, if none, i'll sum it up myself someday.