# Russell's paradox, the [untagged] tag. What is it for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I came across the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. Of course it's kind of funny and reminiscent of [Russell's paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046863/how-can-a-set-contain-itself): "the tag that tags questions that aren't tagged".

But my question is more on a practical level. What is this tag for and how do we use it? This question, [How to tag an untagged question using a rare technology?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309359), suggests it's a meta tag, but is it? Wasn't it supposed [to be gone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399176/861716)? Is see in the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) that it was added yesterday. Should it be removed again?

Either way, it would be useful for the tag to have a guidance explaining its purpose and restrictions, if any.

As suggested by Jeanne Dark, I tried to add the tag to a question and got this:

> The 'untagged' tag is not allowed.
>
> This tag is for use by the system for questions that have had all other tags removed. Please use a real tag instead.

Which establishes that it's a special tag indeed.

Comment: Maybe if a question without tags existing on SO is migrated to SO. See also [Can the untagged followers please attend to their tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399176/11682469) and [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372560/11682469).

Comment: @JeanneDark Thanks, but I just discovered that it was added yesterday. It seems it's just a normal tag now that shouldn't be there. Hence, I don't think the duplicate applies.

Comment: I saw that but it's not correct. When you check the revision history, you see that it was apparently added back in May. So I guess it was not a normal process but maybe it only had one tag left that somehow got removed. Did you try to add [tag:untagged] to a question yourself? If you do, you'll get a warning explaining it.

Comment: @JeanneDark Good suggestion! I did, see my edit.

Comment: Since you can't manually add the tag, what would a guidance be useful for? It's just added by the system in some special cases when there's no other tag (migration, tag removal), it can't be added manually. The whole guidance necessary is that when you see a question with that tag, you should probably try to edit it (though not in case of that newer question because it'll Roomba anyway).

Comment: Related discussion on MSE: [Why do some 'untagged' tags miss an excerpt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295111/241919), related proposal on MSE since 2011: [Users should not be able to suggest tag wikis for 'untagged'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111508/241919) (the question asked for a different thing, but the answer proposed something similar to this)

Comment: You can [search for tags mentioned in posts](/search?q=url:%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Funtagged). There’s also [What happens to questions whose tags are burned down?](/q/260736/4642212), [Why are there suddenly 25 \[untagged\] questions, and what should we do with them?](/q/378917/4642212) and [Retagging of 7 special \[untagged\] questions?](/q/296226/4642212).

Comment: Is that system message as hard to read live as it is in your screenshot? Seems like there should be a bug report for that as well. (Maybe increase the contrast.)

Comment: @BSMP It's just a screen shot, it didn't appear hard to read to me though.

Comment: If you're here, remember to vote to close and delete the question there so that the tag is gone by the end of the day.

Comment: There is an entire FAQ about why the image isn't helpful though, @GertArnold : [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Just because it's meta doesn't make the points raised not applicable.

Comment: @Larnu Ironically, I know all about that FAQ.

Comment: Your question asks "What is it for?" Doesn't the linked duplicate answer your question?

Comment: @TheMaster A question is more than the title. Also, I wonder if you followed all comments and revisions.

Comment: Yes, but the title is the summary of the entire question. Kindly edit to provide a better title.

Comment: Pedantic note, but Russell's paradox would be "a tag which tags those tags which do not tag themselves", or something. This isn't a paradox, and isn't even necessarily a contradiction - it's a tag which is only used on questions which don't have any tags. Logically, that's fine as long as all questions have tags and none have *this* tag, which happens to be the case at the time of writing.